# jQuery UI - Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'tabs' (in jade)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, pug

Can't seem to get this translated HTML...

Anyway, I went over all the existing answers and made sure:

1. Syntax is correct
2. jQuery loaded before jQuery UI loaded before my script (I even put then on opposite ends of the page...)
3. made sure jade compiles to html correctly

So yeah, still not working. Anyone got some ideas?

Code:

Part 1:

```
link(rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css")
script(src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js")
script(src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js")
```

Part 2:

```
#tabs
  ul
    li 
     a(href='#tabs-1') Tab 1
    li 
     a(href='#tabs-2') Tab 2
    li 
     a(href='#tabs-3') Tab 2
    #tabs-1
    #tabs-2
    #tabs-2
```

Part 3:

```
script.
  $(function() {
     $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
});
```

Whole thing:

```
doctype html

html(lang='en')
head
    meta(charset='utf-8')
    meta(http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible', content='IE=edge')
    meta(name='viewport', content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1')
    meta(name='description', content='')
    meta(name='author', content='')
    link(rel='shortcut icon', href='')
    title Starter Template for Bootstrap

    link(href='/css/bootstrap.min.css', rel='stylesheet')
    link(href='/css/mystyles.css', rel='stylesheet')
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='codemirror/lib/codemirror.css')
    link(rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css")
    script(src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js")
    script(src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js")


  body
   form(name='uploadDL', id='uploadDL', action = '/sendDL', method = 'post')
    .navbar.navbar-inverse.navbar-fixed-top(role='navigation')
      .container-fluid
        .navbar-header
          button.navbar-toggle(type='button', data-toggle='collapse', data-target='.navbar-collapse')
            span.sr-only Toggle navigation
            span.icon-bar
            span.icon-bar
            span.icon-bar
          a.navbar-brand(href='#') DL in JS
        .collapse.navbar-collapse
          ul.nav.navbar-nav
              button.btn.btn-default.navbar-btn(type="submit") Run
        //
          /.nav-collapse 
    br
    .container-fluid
      .col-md-3
          textarea(name = "DLCode", id="DLcode") x=1;y=x+1;z=x+y;t=z+x;a=x+x+x;
      .col-md-9
        .canvas
          #tabs
            ul
              li 
                a(href='#tabs-1') Tab 1
              li 
                a(href='#tabs-2') Tab 2
              li 
                a(href='#tabs-3') Tab 2
            #tabs-1
            #tabs-2
            #tabs-2



       Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster 
    script(src='codemirror/lib/codemirror.js')
    script(src='codemirror/mode/javascript/javascript.js')
    script.
      var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById("DLcode"), {lineNumbers: true,mode: "javascript"});

    script(src='/js/bootstrap.min.js')
    script(src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js")
    script(src="http://mbostock.github.com/d3/d3.js")   
    script(src='/d3graph.js')
    script.
       $(uploadDL).on('submit', 'form', function(e) {
       var form = e.currentTarget;
       $.ajax({
       url: form.action,         
       type: 'POST',                                             
       data: $(form).serialize(), 
       success: function(response) {renderGraph(response);},
       error: function() {}
       });  
       e.preventDefault();
       });
    script.
      $(function() {
           $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
      });
```

Comment: in your browser console you you test `$ == jQuery`

Comment: @ArunPJohny Getting true, and I tried using `jQuery` instead of `$` as well. And that other script works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is `confliction of jquery` try this,

```
jQuery(function() {
     jQuery( "#tabs" ).tabs();
});
```

Also, you have included jquery twice, remove the second one.

```
script(src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js")
```

Comment: It was actually the second thing, I guess when I looked it over the different url threw me off :| It being this dumb is almost as frustrating as having it not work. Thanks.